# best way to check download duration of a file from multiple urls in python (threading or async)?

Tags: python, multithreading, asynchronous

What is the best way to check the download duration of a file from like 50 urls? I would like to download from each file using my entire bandwidth, should i use multi threading or co-routines or just plain old synchronous way? why?

This is the code i use to check the download duration from a single url:

```
import urllib
import time

start = time.time()
with urllib.urlopen('http://example.com/file') as response:
    data = response.read()
    end = time.time()

duration = end - start
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multithreading and coroutines in Python are still restricted by the [Global Interpreter Lock (GIL)](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock) to only run one Python instruction at a time. If Python code uses multithreading or coroutines on regular Python code that just performs a parallel calculation with no delays for things like input or output, then it doesn't actually execute in parallel. Because each of your threads would be delayed by the download, they are I/O bound.

Because the downloads are completely I/O bound, multithreading or coroutines should both work fine. If you're concerned about overhead, I would just compare results with the two versions.

If you really are just throwing away the downloaded data from large files, consider using streaming and the [`iter_content` method](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/api/?highlight=iter_content#requests.Response.iter_content) to avoid holding more data in memory than you need.

Comment: I am new to concurrency so can you explain ? Do you mean even if I use multi threading or coroutines the downloading takes place one url after the other ?

Comment: I added an explanation of the GIL, @Shankar.